# Aggregation data design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, mongoose-populate

I am new to MongoDB and I have data in the table name doctors

```
[
  {
    _id: "610d0f36a793342c08b49b0a",
    hospitals: [
      {
        _id: "6166c2ea807d823f20722d52",
        hospital: "6166c2ea807d823f20722d4f"
      },
      {
        _id: "61cd446d20c97e302c667e89",
        hospital: "61cd446d20c97e302c667e87"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

2nd table name weekdays

```
 [
  {
    _id: "6166c2ea807d823f20722d4f",
    hospitalId: "615442355273d22b90b92491",
    fee: "800"
  },
  {
    _id: "61cd446d20c97e302c667e87",
    hospitalId: "615d4ebc5521472af0aae53d",
    fee: "1000"
  }
]
```

3rd table name hospitals

```
  [
  {
    _id: "615442355273d22b90b92491",
    hospitalName: "ABC"
  },
  {
    _id: "615d4ebc5521472af0aae53d",
    hospitalName: "ABC"
  }
]
```

If I use

```
db.doctors.find().populate({
          path: "hospitals.hospital",
          populate: {
            path: "hospitalId",
            select: "hospitalName",
          },
        })
```

I get result in this format

```
[
  {
    _id: "610d0f36a793342c08b49b0a",
    hospitals: [
      {
        _id: "6166c2ea807d823f20722d52",
        hospital: {
          _id: "6166c2ea807d823f20722d4f",
          fee: "800",
          hospitalId: {
            _id: "615442355273d22b90b92491",
            hosptialName: "ABC"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        _id: "61cd446d20c97e302c667e89",
        hospital: {
          _id: "61cd446d20c97e302c667e87",
          fee: "1000",
          hospitalId: {
            _id: "615d4ebc5521472af0aae53d",
            hosptialName: "ABC"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I am achieving this kind of result using the aggregation
When I `

```
db.doctors.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"weekdays", localField:"hospitals.hospital", foreignField:"_id", as:"hospitals"}}])
```

it returns

```
[
  {
    _id: "610d0f36a793342c08b49b0a",
    hospitals: [
      {
        _id: "6166c2ea807d823f20722d52",
        hospitalId: "615442355273d22b90b92491",
        fee: "800"
      },
      {
        _id: 61cd446d20c97e302c667e89,
        hospitalId: "615d4ebc5521472af0aae53d",
        fee: 800
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

how to achieve the result like I am getting from find query using the aggregate.

Comment: You may use https://mongoplayground.net/ to prettify your sample data.

Comment: Okay I have formatted the data. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: No, what you show is not the result you would get, see [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Hb1CB12XQb) Please provide valid sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so basically .populate is a method by mongoose. [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

I am assuming you wanted the result from the aggregation to be like this shown below.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "111",
    "hospitals": [
      {
        "_id": "331",
        "fee": "800",
        "hospital": {
          "_id": "441",
          "hospitalName": "ABC"
        },
        "hospitalId": "441"
      },
      {
        "_id": "332",
        "fee": "1000",
        "hospital": {
          "_id": "442",
          "hospitalName": "ABC"
        },
        "hospitalId": "442"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So to achieve this you will need to `$unwind` arrays and do a `$lookup` again with the 3rd collection `hospitals` and `$unwind` again before grouping them up.
Here is the [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e4y1HBRjssZ) link

```
db.doctors.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "weekdays",
      localField: "hospitals.hospital",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "hospitals"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hospitals"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "hospitals",
      localField: "hospitals.hospitalId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "hospitals.hospital"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hospitals.hospital"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "hospitals": {
        "$push": "$hospitals"
      }
    }
  }
])
```